# Parse as multi-tenant SaaS service

Tags: parse-server

I would like to build task system (kind of github). 
I want to organize my data as following: organization -> project -> task
This is a multi-tenant application (each node should be able to handle requests from multiple tenants).

I was thinking of using separate DB for each project.
But the problem is that I need global “users” collection - the user should be able to participate in different organizations and projects accordingly.
So probably it should be one parse application.
As soon as service will be shared it probably makes sense to store all projects not in one collection by put each project into the separate collection which will help with sharing and scaling.

What are the potential problems of this kind of approach?
Any recommendations?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The last people who tried this ran out of money and shut down...

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I'm sure that each architecture has some limits... What the limit (or boatneck) in this approach?

Comment: parse.com? I'm sure you heard of them.

Comment: I'm not sure that ran out of money was a real reason... it's another subject for discussion.. =)

Comment: I know this is much later, but Parse is still very much alive and I'm facing some similar questions. For those interested, I've got a thread going [here](https://community.parseplatform.org/t/multi-tenant-implementation/1270/24) where I'm documenting my questions and findings.